# All books download on iPhone but also sync reading position and bookmarks?

Tags: iphone, icloud, books

I'd like to store all my books locally on my iPhone, but also continue to sync my reading progress and bookmarks across devices. How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the app  you are using to download and read your books on your iPhone? What is your iPhone model and which iOS is installed on it? What are the other devices you wish to synchronize across and what program are you using to download and read books on them? What are the operating system versions on those devices? Pls update your question to include these details.

Comment: IMHO better wording needed. As I understand current wording OP wants sync bookmarks and reading progress without syncing books themselves…

Comment: Have you thought of the built-in Books app? It does what you want I think. It sync's all infos from Books (reading %, bookmarks, etc.) between your devices (connected to the same Apple ID).